# Conditional in MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not working how I'd like it to

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I'd like to add a row and give the column named `count` a value of 1, except if the row already exists - then I'd like to reduce the value of `count` by 1, but only if `count` is not already 0.

This doesn't throw an error, but it always sets the value to 0 (instead of reducing the current value by 1) regardless if the original value is eg 7...

```
INSERT INTO `requestCount` (`requesterID`, `count` ) 
    VALUES ( '1407181', 1 ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE `requesterID`=`requesterID`, 
            `count` = IF(`count` <> 0, `count`=`count`-1, `count`)
```

Could someone please explain the correct way to code this, plus why the above always sets `count` to 0?

Thank you.

Comment: May be ``` `count` = IF(`count` <> 0, `count` - 1, `count`) ```

Comment: Always Zero because you are always passing in 1

Comment: @RiggsFolly probably he needs `count + 1` not `count -1`